# Trigger Toolkit - Install in non System Drive

Tags: installation, trigger.io

I'm new to Trigger.io. I noticed there's no option to choose where Trigger Toolkit will be installed (Windows 7 32-bit). It always installs on C: drive (the System Drive). 
My android SDK, AVD are on D: drive. When I go to local config, I can only browse within C: drive. I don't want to keep the Android folder, and even my app code, on System drive (It may have to be formatted without taking a back-up).

So my question is: Can trigger toolkit be installed anywhere, or do I have to copy my Android folder to C: drive? Also, can the Toolkit only browse in the drive it is installed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a story in our backlog to support switching between drives in the Toolkit - it's definitely on our radar.

In the meantime, can you can manually edit your local_config.json file (sitting alongside your src directory) to include the drive in the relevant paths?